# HTML how to increase <blink> tag blinking timing

Tags: css, html

How to increase html blink tag fade in out timing

```
 <blink>
     <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
     +01 0000 111 111
 </blink>
```

using only html

Comment: `<blink>` is not a standard way of doing what you want to do and is not supported by all browsers. Better use CSS / JS for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML 'blink' tag is obsolete. Moreover The blink() method is not standard, and may not work as expected in all browsers. You can use JavaScript for your requirement.

```js
function blink() {
  setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("blink").style.webkitTransitionDuration = "0.5s";
    document.getElementById("blink").style.opacity = 0;
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("blink").style.webkitTransitionDuration = "0.5s";
      document.getElementById("blink").style.opacity = 1;
    }, 500);
  }, 1500);
}
blink();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="blink"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>+01 0000 111 111</div>
```

Here you can change the duration as well.

Comment: Double the interval to 1s. Because animation is broken ;)

Answer (score 3):

Since `<blink>` is deprecated you should not use it because some browsers may not support it. But if you still want the blinking effect you can make a simple css animations and then add that animation to a element you want to make blinking.

Here is an example of such animation

```
@keyframes blink_effect {
    0% {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    50% {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    100% {
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

And then you can add that animation to e.g. a class

```
.blink {
    animation: .1s blink_effect infinite
}
```

```css
@keyframes blink_effect {
  0% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  50% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  100% {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}

.blink {
  animation: .1s blink_effect infinite
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="blink"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>+01 0000 111 111</div>
```